# WordPress: Query posts by date range

Tags: php, wordpress, date, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on pages in a WordPress site to show "Upcoming" and "Archived" events by date range using custom fields for `event_start_date` and `event_end_date` with the custom post type `event`. I'd like the "Upcoming" page to show posts for which the current date falls within this range and/or equals the start date or end date; and the "Archive" page to show events for which the current date is after the date range entirely. Thus, if today is October 10, and an event with the dates October 9-11 or October 10-12 would show on "Upcoming" and an event with any previous dates would show on the "Archived" page.

I'm including my queries below for both the upcoming and archive pages; the query for upcoming seems to be working ok, but in the archive page if the current date falls within the date range it will still show, and I'd like it to *only* show past events:

```
/* upcoming events query */
$event_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'event',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => 10,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        'orderby'       =>  'meta_value_num',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),

        ),
    );

/* archived events query */
$event_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'event',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => 10,
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        'orderby'       =>  'meta_value_num',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '<',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '<',
            ),

        ),
    );
```

Thus, the `meta_query` for the upcoming events query seems to be working for all cases, but that for the archive page is not behaving as intended. Thank you for any assistance here, and please let me know if my question is unclear in any way. **EDIT** I initially neglected to mention that I also need to account for the scenario in which *only a start date is entered*, i.e. for single-day events, which is proving to be a sticking point for the archive page query.

Answer (score 1):

In your archive query, you are using two `meta_query` conditions, I think the issue is with the first condition

First condition: `event_start_date`

```
array(
    'key'     => 'event_start_date',
    'type'    => 'DATE',
    'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
    'compare' => '<',
),
```

This will query all events if the `event_start_date` is less than `current_time`. Also consider that you are creating an `OR` relation.

Now, let's say today is Oct 10 and an even spans from Oct 9 to Oct 12, the above `meta_query` will include this event as well because the `event_start_date` is less than `current_time`. Make sense?

The solution will be to include `meta_query` for `event_end_date` only. This way, only events with ending date less than `current_time` will be queried.

```
/* archived events query */
$event_args = array(
    'post_type'             =>  'event',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => 10,
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'paged'                 => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'orderby'               =>  'meta_value_num',
    'order'                 =>  'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'     => 'event_end_date',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
            'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '<',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Update:**
Nested `meta_query` logic to handle single day past events as well.

```
/* archived events query */
$event_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'event',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => 10,
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'orderby'       =>  'meta_value_num',
    'order'         =>  'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_start_date',
            'type'    => 'DATE',
            'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '<',
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                'compare' => '<',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'event_end_date',
                'type'    => 'DATE',
                'value'   => NULL,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: thanks for the response- I should have specified that I need to account for instances in which only a start date is specified, i.e. for events that are just a single day; thus, I need the archive template to still take both dates into account- any idea on how to incorporate that scenario as well?

Comment: I think you could get all the possible events by my method and then filter them while looping through it, i.e. don't display an event if `event_start_date` exists or however your events plugin/manager is managing the two types of events.

Comment: I'm not using any kind of plugin or event manager- just a simple custom post type with custom fields and need to find the right query.

Comment: if an event is for the whole day only, what's the value/state of `event_start_date`, `event_end_date` and what other custom field is populated?

Comment: The way it's currently configured is with just those two fields, and if an event is only one day, that date would be entered into `event_start_date`, and `event_end_date` would be left blank.

Comment: @Junaid- thanks again; using your updated code, events with a date range now appear in the archive as expected, but events with only a start date (and no end date) that occur in the past *don't* now show- however, if I specify the same past date for start/end, it *does* show in the archive as expected- any thoughts?

Comment: Updated the code. Just changed one value. Please test now.

Comment: @Junaid- unfortunately it's still not working for a single start date in the past, with no end date entered, for some reason. Not sure if you have any other ideas? If I enter the *same* day for start and end in the past, it does work as expected, and I might just tell the client for single day events to list it in both.

Comment: I think you should use only `event_start_date` condition and then filter out events whose end date is greater than now, means they are still happening.